# While loop not running because of if loops

Tags: python-3.x

Friends,

I have written a code that takes input from user and then ssh me to a server. But this is just working once although a infinite loop is present. I want that while loop runs again and again. But after giving user input, it runs once but not again.

```
while True:
    print('Enter name of server...')

    print('......................................................................')

    server = input ('')

    if server == '1':
        cmd1='p -ssh 192.168.1.12'
        os.system(cmd1)
    if server == '2':
        cmd1='p -ssh 192.168.1.13'
        os.system(cmd1)
    if server == '3':
        cmd1='p -ssh 192.168.1.14'
        os.system(cmd1)
```

Comment: Lets say when you give '1' as input, it ssh to 192.168.1.12 and exits immediately?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Any sugesstion?

Answer (score 0):

Because it blocked at the `os.system(cmd1)`

What's your purpose to ssh the server? Maybe you can have a view on the [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko): a ssh python lib. If your cmd may block, you can also have a view on [python threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)  and [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue)

Just like :

```
import threading

class ssh_client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ssh_host):
        super(ssh_client, self).__init__()
        self.ssh_host = ssh_host

    def run(self):
        """Do something
        """
        pass

    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        print('Enter name of server...')

        print('......................................................................')

        server = input ('')

        if server == '1':
            ssh_client_1 = ssh_client("192.168..1.12")
            ssh_client_1.start()
        if server == '2':
            ssh_client_1 = ssh_client("192.168..1.13")
            ssh_client_2.start()
```

For python3 user, the `paramiko` is'nt a python3 compatible ssh library, you can use `subprocess` or the ssh library: [pylibssh2 python bindings for libssh2 library](https://github.com/wallix/pylibssh2)

for subprocess: 
[subprocess_ssh.py](https://gist.github.com/niwibe/2431088)

Comment: Yes it looks promising. I will try it. But I am unable to understand the meaning of these lines: class ssh_client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ssh_host):
        super(ssh_client, self).__init__()
        self.ssh_host = ssh_host

Comment: these lines define a `child class` of `threading.Thread`, So the program is multi thread. So when you open a new ssh client , it will not block in the main thread, because each command we start a new thread. For more infomation you can have a view on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/ or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Ok, understood, but it is still not working. Still I am able to open only one ssh login.

Comment: what your intention of open a ssh client? Maybe you  can try [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) or [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko)

Comment: Your thinking is right, but I am using Python 3.3. So I can't use paramiko . :(

Comment: Sure, paramiko does'nt work with Python 3, I update my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an issue with the 'p -ssh 192.168.1.14' commands.

For example, if you just use the ssh command, the looping works, and when you exit the remote server, you are again asked to "Enter name of server"

For example:

```
>>> while True:

...   print('Enter name of server...')
...   print('......................................................................')

...   server = input ('')
...   if server == '1':
...     cmd1='ssh remote_server_1'
...     os.system(cmd1)

...   if server == '2':
...     cmd1='ssh remote_server_2'
...     os.system(cmd1)

...   if server == '3':
...     cmd1='ssh remote_server_3'
...     os.system(cmd1)
... 

Enter name of server...
......................................................................
'1'
erica@remote_server's password: 

       __|  __|_  )  Amazon Linux AMI
       _|  (     /     Beta
      ___|\___|___|

See /usr/share/doc/system-release-2011.02 for latest release notes. :-)
[erica@remote_server ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to remote_server closed.
0
Enter name of server...
......................................................................
```